# Typing custom `useDispatch` hook with `unwrapResult` from redux-toolkit

Tags: typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a custom hook that wraps `react-redux`'s `useDispatch` method and notifies me if rejected. The problem is that I can't infer the resolved type.

```
// useAction
type AnyFn = (...s: any[]) => any;

export default <T extends AnyFn>(actionCreator: T) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<(action: any) => Promise<any>>(); // * Note Promise<any>

  const action = useCallback((...args: Parameters<typeof actionCreator>) => {
    return dispatch(actionCreator(...args))
      .then(result => {
        return unwrapResult(result) // @reduxjs/toolkit
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // the reason this hook is needed
        // notify error ... then
        return Promise.reject(err)
      })
    }, [dispatch])

  return [action] as const;
}
```

```
// action
const fetchUsersActionCreator = createAsyncThunk(
  'fetch', (id: number) => Promise.resolve([id]) // return type IUser[]
)

// consumer
const [fetchUsers] = useAction(fetchUsersActionCreator);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchUsers()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.length) // Property 'length' does not exist on type PayloadAction<IUser[]...
    })
}, [fetchUsers])

// But if I unwrap results here the result type is inferred correctly

useEffect(() => {
  fetchUsers()
    .then(unwrapResult)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.length) // OK
    })
}, [fetchUsers])
```

So, how could I type the `useAction` hook so that the resolved type is inferred from the return type of `unwrapResult`? I know it's somewhere related to the typings of `useDispatch` but I can't put my finger on it...

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: I've specified that the action is an async thunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, it might be useful for others trying to achieve the same functionality.

Thank you @phry and @linda-paiste for your answers as it pointed me to the right direction.

```
import { unwrapResult, AsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { AppDispatch } from '../store'; // type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

// useAction aka useAsyncThunk
export default <Arg, Returned>(
  actionCreator: AsyncThunk<Returned, Arg, {}>
) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  return useCallback((arg: Arg) => {
    return dispatch(actionCreator(arg))
    .then(result => {
      return unwrapResult(result) // @reduxjs/toolkit
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // the reason this hook is needed
      // notify error ... then
      return Promise.reject(err)
    })
  }, [dispatch, actionCreator])
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your problem would already solve itself if you used a `useDispatch` type that is typed as [described in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type):

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>() // Export a hook that can be reused to resolve types
```

If that doesn't help, you can copy out & use the `PayloadForActionTypesExcludingErrorActions` type from [the RTK source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/23a0e43149503198bc56014a63b8572162631519/src/createAsyncThunk.ts#L473), but keep in mind that this behaviour will change slightly with the next release when [this PR](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/704) will be merged. If you need to copy that type, you'll probably need to adjust that with the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've tried that before but `useAppDispatch` isn't even promise like, maybe because I have an enhanced store? output: `const useAppDispatch: () => ThunkDispatch<{ router: ..., user: ... }, null, AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<...> & Dispatch<...>`

Comment: useAppDispatch itself is not promise like, but calling useAppDispatch with a thunk as an argument (and only then!) should return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

The `action` function in your `useAction` hook is a function which takes the same arguments as the `actionCreator` and returns a `Promise` which resolves to the `payload` property of the created action.

I don't love all of the backwards inference here, and I don't know why you are returning a 1-length tuple instead of returning the function directly, but this return type should work based on your current code.  You can remove the `readonly` if you remove `as const` from your return.

```
const useAction = <T extends AnyFn>(
    actionCreator: T
): readonly [(...args: Parameters<typeof actionCreator>) => Promise<ReturnType<typeof actionCreator>['payload']>]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmARYKwEMYDGAFgL5wBmUEIcARFGrgTALQMAmSAHrQNwCwAKFCRYiVGgDCuADYyARkwDWAGjgSAouXJpmZStToMmMPkJHR4yAHYB3KLjAAlNCiQyY%20qjVoABDtwAVigA9DAQEDJKwKYCgkIhIeroAILMwBDWQjAAnmBocCnWOQBi1nAAvHAAFAB09SgAXHC4xQDaALoAlJUAfC3FcUIEmSjwEmkwGeVVADwAKnBoXDBo1uwohcVlvdUm05LG4VDN813NxuyZMjlwbXX1uFAA5k1wAApPuCBoq1Aos1y%20Qg5Ba6Uyh0Yx16PQq-Xe3mwaFmLhgSCg1nmeWRQLQILBUwhR2gvTaAHI8DkZBBcOwyR1eh0%20oghHA4CNrGM4OxsHhCERKslMLz8MRZntwdZmq0crD4Yj0LMZb1dl1eHBEnAAFRwAByEFWHwVyOVQlZ7NG8H2mUFEmkckUBCU1QetSer2anwcPz%20ANx%20Ot1kh%20BJcpZgjZbIYaIx3JF-IlhKDxKgrvdKC6XXNkbgtRgRDW1QYbg8zIQ2ZzcGj6PKSDsDmcrncMCLTY8PU1-jQnC4wTCESiMQrbJIWYjldqBFFRGqaCgUDLw8jmvzBWMKBt%20ewcCIESUcG31jQ3e7S7ZmusBuA5Fuc6oC-qtTgq6y48rVd%20NaN1CRtQYgV0Fs7zHd9RwrEg1DaHkcGnbozXHatYzaQMmVwTYOTGOISHgjD4B0fkAFV0H%20SYDhTQVqjDapy3HXFmloEoNHmSQAAkAH0CIAZQ0JxONoFRzUpalaWaNoEGAdhmgARhIDohDA%20JBFwuBJFGJAfgXKpKMXcdNQw9S53NZS2nw4giLnFAmSqCZJWqUyiHMkjJWDY41XgtlNG0QCXTDGic3sxyUEopc8wLawXWLZtfLPC1OUiNBampZ5WxLGBErWZ58w7JIEQgfJYFuMkZAy-MyW5CBXDgS94GWbB4E3bEPlwKkaXYUjMlmABJRzOkfJcFJHSCAuIyyx3NTUACEkHga84E69R60cD9Us2AsGGfAtlubZ9Gu3YBrB0eduwtI7mBudyhS0HRmB8nT-N%20MyRuCt9I1Cws63sRwXFSkCJxfCK2xgaKXpzDD4sSiBksijx0usTKiGyuAAHkAGl%20t%20iC7mGiy4MEEggA)

I would write it like this:

```
const useAction = <Args extends any[], Action extends PayloadAction<any, any>>(
  actionCreator: (...args: Args) => Action
): (...args: Args) => Promise<Action['payload']> => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<(action: any) => Promise<any>>(); // * Note Promise<any>

  return useCallback(async (...args: Args) => {
    return dispatch(actionCreator(...args))
      .then(result => {
        return unwrapResult(result) // @reduxjs/toolkit
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return Promise.reject(err)
      })
  }, [dispatch])
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMAixVgIYwDGAFnAL5wBmUEIcARFOnoTALRMAmyAHvQNwBYAFChIsRCgwBhPABs5AIxYBrADRT0AUUqV0rclRp1GzVgJFjo8JMgB2Adyh4wAJXSpkcmBoAKeAE85CDxOAEFWYAg7Q2paBgABLl4AK1QAehgICDkVYBgLYRFCaNR4NHQImCiYgF44AB4wqABzVDh0Hhh0O052vDsAgG0AXQ0qmo6unr64fyCQ8MjohoGAjTWAPk2AChE4OBZq6OkmAmgALjgdgDo7vFbUK%20a2gEo4Ws24CeiRV6vbvdHs9Hu9PnNjDh0E1lnYhgByfALULwkZfcEIfZwEp2MpwTg4fBEUj1CrYXAEEgNHZHGpXNZgr6%20SEYVaDbY7V78ODpdJwABUcAAchBuhDaFC2QFNiIsUwYMgoDEKrIFMpCCoaagAnZCNc7jcHm0QW8Pl9McIDgd5YqYgSKcSabDTswslBAYbQa8sVa4DcYMQejsmJ5vGbED7fXAbUqUI5nG4PF4YMGk953ry4El0NweGlMtlcvlIwcyN7LVGboRKcQdugoFBwxao1aYzFmRKMDcmCl9Cn61Byy2y1iyBohvaiSQRuWyLLhDi8XpiQBVDBQVA-Owu86N%20qc8M7ZtwGABMDoK70ABiWgAKtIABIAfRXAGUtK5X-Q1FikcFQlcQxIMAnBXAAjOQIwiCORQLqU8DSKUyAgPWHzXIyEYVpmi7IfWWKLvAy4kGu9btKSGBbjsRHECRG5bjubpcvOBwVDoeisDsB4YpG1G0agnIln6AZBqmoYwBhx4touOToDcwQtKJyZyT0LQBhmfIduesABHA8JyCpAbwviEAeHAdiilMODwNEJ5nugcyBP%20SzHHYDQAJK0aMBqCTBpbjrx66oDOzE8nyABCyDwMAlBwG5cZOC40ZpjA7SBkwJ6BklYm2eecA4Hldh6A2ObYtATCsHIAQhaxuh9pxEk8egq6BQJFa%20v6gZ2Ds9gJYmYlDpWwldYp6ZNoJBzSfpckQApIZKfpdiqcQ6lwAA8gA0j5A1jnAQwBaRwXCGQQA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the resolved type is not inferred here, I created a [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-s3zmu) and result is still any

Comment: Yeah, wrapping the return in an array was because previously I had more items, but I've removed it since.